# Is it ok to reduce this equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the next equation and it is necessary to integrate both sides:
$$\dfrac{d(x_0x_1)}{dz}=-8\dfrac{dx_0}{dz}(r_i-z(r_i-1))$$
Is it ok to reduce this equation with $dz$, because of term $r_i-z(r_i-1)$, but $dz$ is on both sides? 
In that case I would get this equation:
$$d(x_0x_1)=-8dx_0(r_i-z(r_i-1))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{d(x_0x_1)}{dz}=-8\dfrac{dx_0}{dz}(r_i-z(r_i-1))$$
This symbolism supposes that $x_0$ and $x_1$ are some functions of $z$, namely $x_0(z)$ and $x_1(z)$.
$$d(x_0x_1)=-8(r_i-z(r_i-1))dx_0\quad\text{is correct.}$$
But it is of no use to integrate both sides because the right side is not a total differential.
$$x_0x_1=-8(r_i-z(r_i-1))x_0+C\quad\text{is not correct.}$$
One cay write :$\quad d(x_0x_1)=-8r_i dx_0+8(r_i-1)zdx_0$

$$x_0x_1=-8r_ix_0+8(r_i-1)\int z\:dx_0$$
where $z$ is function of $x_0$, namely $z(x_0)$ , in other words the inverse function of $x_0(z)$.

Or, if you prefer :
$$x_0x_1=-8r_ix_0+8(r_i-1)\int z\left(\frac{dx_0}{dz}\right)dz$$

The above integrals cannot be evaluated or simplified or put on closed form without more information about the function $x_0(z)$ .

Comment: If at this point of calculation I have just fact that  $x_0$ is dependent only on $z$, $x_0=f(z)$, is that enough for some result? From the other side, I have that $x_0=\sqrt{1+64\beta(1-z)}$, should I differentiate according to $z$, and then integrate?

Comment: If $x_0(z)$ is a known function one can integrate in some cases (The antiderivative of all functions have not always a closed form). In case of  $x_0=\sqrt{1+64\beta(1-z)}$ it is easy to compute $\frac{dx_0}{dz}$ and $\int z\left(\frac{dx_0}{dz}\right)dz=-32\beta+C$.

Comment: And what if I made mistake and the first equation is $\dfrac{d(x_0x_1)}{dz}=−8\dfrac{dx_0}{dz}\dfrac{1}{(r_i−z(r_i−1))}$? And $p_0=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{64-192(r_i−z(r_i−1))}{3(1-r_i)(r_i−z(r_i−1))^3}}$?

Comment: You just have to proceed on the same manner. Compute $\frac{dx_0}{dz}$ and then the integral. See if a closed form exists for the integral. Bravo if you succeed. Sorry, I am too lazy to try it.